# does this design look suitable for a 4-bit adder

Tags: resistors, breadboard, adder

I am working on a project that will include a basic 4-bit adder, I have designed a layout is Adobe Illustrator and would like people to check over it to see if it looks like it should work. I am very new to this side of electronics and don't entirely know what I am doing.
The IC's are as follows:
http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=M74HC08B1Rvirtualkey51120000virtualkey511-M74HC08
http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=SN74HC86NE4virtualkey59500000virtualkey595-SN74HC86NE4
http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=L7805ABVvirtualkey51120000virtualkey511-L7805ABV
http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/SN74HC32N/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuyBeSSR239IT5Ta765RsfIl7Z%252bPKBp%2fGI%3d

All of this is going to be on this breadboard:
http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=TW-E40-1020virtualkey58930000virtualkey589-TW-E40-1020

The switches are these:
http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/CK-Components/BD01/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMv%2f%252b2JhlA6ysMM4cIGc%2fmHBGn0VI%2fQp1N0%3d

And the lights are these:
http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Lumex/SSF-LXH400SRD/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtAPyr1PQZl3x9IHrxpF7wHvobBBX3aJ9s%3d

I want to make sure all of this will run properly and I don't know where all I need to put resistors or capacitors. The running voltage will be 5. This is my planned layout:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feWCWu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is pretty cluttered so if you need something more visible, then I can try and upload the AI file that is organized. 
With these lights, would it be a good idea to put a 250 ohm resistor on the supply? (5V/20mA=0.25=250 ohm?)

thanks

Comment: This is going be incomprehensible unless you put it into schematic format... Please create a schematic for it. You can do this right from the website, by going into Edit mode and pressing Ctrl + M (or clicking the schematic button). Or post a picture from your favorite schematic capture program.

Comment: I can't decipher that layout drawing - I think that a schematic is required before anyone can make any comment on the design.  What are those red blocks at the right?  The only comment I can make on the design at this point is that you must _always_ have current-limiting resistors in series with the LEDs.

Comment: The only person that should have to reverse-engineer a breadboard wiring back into a schematic is the person doing the actual breadboard wiring. Inflicting it on others is like being a doctor and making someone read your [bad] handwriting.

Comment: @Chris Laplante here is a schematic, I put 250 ohm resistors before the lights, would it be advisable to due so also before the supplies on the IC's, and if so, what size?

Comment: @PeterBennett Same as above

Comment: @BlendingJake Thank you for making the schematic :)  I'll flag to see if it can get reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use smaller resistor values, or none at all, with the LEDs. Most CMOS gates, operated at 5 V, will not be able to supply 20 mA anyway so there is little risk of damaging the LEDs. However, it is essential that you add a pulldown resistor on the right side of each switch (the side connected to the gates). Otherwise your gate inputs will be floating when the switch is open, which leads to very bizarre and unpredictable behavior. The value of the resistor is not critical. You probably want something over 10k just to reduce the power consumption and 100k might be a reasonable upper limit to make sure the inputs are pulled down to ground well.

This a purely combinational circuit operating at very low speed, so bypass capacitors on the power supply pins aren't needed.

Comment: ok, thanks. when you say between 10k and 100k do you mean bewtween 10 and 100 ohms?

Comment: No, I meant between 10,000 and 100,000 ohms.

Comment: ok, thanks, that makes a little more sense now that I think about it

Comment: does this look like an ok one? http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Xicon/271-10K-RC/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtlubZbdhIBIMB9x5pP3%252bdkgQ3fqWomerM%3d Thanks for all of your help

Comment: Sure, that will work. You can save some money by purchasing resistors with a 5% tolerance instead, since the value isn't critical in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're implementing a relatively straightforward ripple-carry adder.  It looks like it would probably work, though the wiring is a bit of a rat's nest.

An alternative approach also using five DIPs, but without such a rat's nest, would be to use four 74HC153 chips and a quad XOR.  The 74HC153 chip contains two four-input multiplexers with common select lines; each multiplexer outputs one of four inputs based upon the state of the two select lines.  Wire the two select lines of each multiplexer to the two data inputs associated with a bit.  Use one of the multiplexers to generate a carry out by tying input C0 low (carry out should be low if both data inputs are low), C3 high (high if both inputs are high), and C1 and C2 to the carry from the previous stage.  Use the other multiplexer to generate what the output from each stage would be without a carry in: tie C0 and C3 low, and C1 and C2 high.

Using this approach, each 74HC153 will generate two outputs which will go to the XOR chip; one of those will also feed the next chip [each stage's "data" output should be xor'ed with the previous stage's "carry" input].  All of the other wiring will be located very close to each chip, and should thus be less prone to becoming a rats nest.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but due to my extremely limited knowledge I will stick with the rats nest. At least until I can gets some rat poison :)

Comment: @BlendingJake: Do whatever works for you, but I suggest playing with the 74HC153--it's a remarkably versatile chip.